# Any word on custom closures, or new ones?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, osl

In an attempt to re-create [Valve's Half-Lambert effect](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Half_Lambert) in cycles, I found out it is basically mathematically impossible at the moment, without patching cycles.  Does anyone know/have heard/rumored/what-have-you anything about more closures, or even better, custom closures?

Comment: A valid question but I think it falls into the 'not so ideal' category. See [How should we handle questions about features not yet in Blender?](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177/how-should-we-handle-questions-about-features-not-yet-in-blender)

Answer (score 3):

This is, in my eyes, not even theoretically possible to implement in Cycles. The backside of an object cannot be influenced by a light source on the front, simply because Cycles works with samples from the camera over the surface towards the lamp. There is no way that a sample bouncing off the surface on the back could directly end up in the light on the other side as there is an object in-between.

However, I don't think this shader is necessary in Cycles. It was built to allow even light setups with very few lights to not look over-contrasted and harsh. With real global illumination, which you have in Cycles, light bouncing off of other objects around your object will automatically (at least with more than 0 diffuse-bounces) provide a smooth light distribution around your object from a single light source, which is exactly the effect the Half-Life developers tried to fake.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "The backside of an object cannot be influenced by a light source on the front". What about the translucent shader? (or SSS or anything similar)

Comment: Translucent/SSS/Glass shaders let samples trough on the front that can then travel through the object through to the back. You could probably program a shader that way that would replicate the behaviour you mentioned, but that would mean that the material on the front has an influence on the back, by deciding which samples to let through in which way, which is not the case in the Half-Lambert example. If you want this behaviour, you can already take a translucent or SSS shader and mix it into your material now.